# JavaFX: difference between methods setOnMouseClicked() and addEventHandler()?

Tags: event-handling, javafx

When I have an object `o` and I want to add an event to it, lets say I want it changes its color when clicked (Let's say it's a `Rectangle` object). What is the difference between:
`o.setNonMouseClicked(){ ... }` and

```
o.addEventHandler(Action.EventAction, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){ ... })
```

How can I make the right choise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it depends on the situation.

The "setOnMouseClicked" will add a new EventHandler to your object. But it will also replace any eventHandler previously added through that method! So if you're planning on changing in runtime the way to react to mouse click, this is the right method.

Now if you just want to add another eventHandler (or several), you should use the "addEventHander" method. Therefore you will have your handlers added on one side. And you will keep the eventHandler added through "setOnMouseClicked" if previously added.

Also beware of the eventHandler or listener you're added because they can lead to severe memory leaks so be sure to remove them when necessary.

Comment: Is it possible that some objects (for example: `BorderPane`) do not support `.addEventHandler();` method?

Comment: The "addEventHandler" and others are implemented in the "Node" class. So if your object is extending Node (which is the case of BorderPane and lots of objects), you will have those method available. 
Anyway, if you have a "setOnXXX", you will have the "addEventHandler".

Check http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/jfxpub-events.htm for more information.

Comment: @Maxoudela `setOnMouseClicked` will not replace your old/already attached event, both will execute.

Comment: If you add two EventHandler using "setOnMouseClicked", only the second one will be executed.